# Create table with table heading using json in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to fetch JSON data and create a table using it with table heading.
I've done it successfully but the problem is that the table is not displayed properly.

```
render(){
    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User_Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Profile Picture</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.arr.map((card)=>{
                        return(
                        <div>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{card.user_name}</td>
                                <td>{card.address}</td>
                                <td>{card.date_of_birth}</td>
                                <td>{card.email}</td>
                                <td>{card.profile_picture}</td>
                                <td><button className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-2 my-2 my-sm-0">Edit</button></td>
                                <td><button className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-2 my-2 my-sm-0">Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                    ) })}
                </tbody>
             </table>
```

and the table looks like this :

https://screenshots.firefox.com/7i07VlkEFYlAj8ga/mrigank.com

I want the table to be properly arranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are mapping your data and returning it into `<tr>`, `<td>` Remove `<div>` while populating the table, because `div` can not be the child of `table`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `div` element from `tbody`.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is not allowed as an immediate child of any of the table elements (except `<th>`, `<td>` and `<caption>`) and will automatically be moved outside of the element with all of its content.

Try removing the `<div>` elements around your `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the table tag `<table style="width:100%">` It will also work.

Or if you want to an absolute table styling use Bootstrap for it so it will be responsive.
Here is the link of tables for [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/)

Also remove the `<div>` tag as it is not recommneded for the table body, But it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code for displaying table properly.

```
 <tbody>
                        {this.state.arr.map((card)=>{
                            return(

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{card.user_name}</td>
                                    <td>{card.address}</td>
                                    <td>{card.date_of_birth}</td>
                                    <td>{card.email}</td>
                                    <td>{card.profile_picture}</td>
                                    <td><button className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-2 my-2 my-sm-0">Edit</button></td>
                                    <td><button className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-2 my-2 my-sm-0">Delete</button></td>
                                </tr>

                        ) })}
                    </tbody>
```